# Scala Multiple Future wrapped in Try

Tags: scala, future

Suppose I have many akka services which all return a case class of type `AbcDto` wrapped in a `Try`.

So I call all these services using `map` and get back a `List[Future[Any]]`.

Now I use `Future.sequence` to convert this to `Future[List[Any]]`.

How do I unwrap my final list of results? I want to process them only when all of them are a `Success` and even if one fails I want to throw an error.

I tried mapping `Future[List[Any]]` as:

```
val a: List[Future[Any]]
a.map {
    case r: List[Success[AbcDto]] => println("hello")
}
```

But this gives error:
`case r: List[Try[AbcDto]]`. At this point its giving error: non-variable type argument `scala.util.Try[AbcDto]` in type pattern `List[scala.util.Try[AbcDto]]` (the underlying of `List[scala.util.Try[AbcDto]]`)

Answer (score 1):

since all akka services return `AbcDto`wrapped in a Try the proper type of `val a` should be `List[Future[Try[AbcDto]]]`. Now the desired result can be achieved by a combination of `Future.sequence` and flatMap operation to check for any Failures in the service as shown below.

```
val a: List[Future[Try[AbcDto]]] = ... 

val result: Future[List[AbcDto]]  = Future.sequence(a) flatMap {
    case r: List[Try[AbcDto]] @unchecked if r.find(!_.isSuccess).isDefined => Future.failed(new RuntimeException("not all results are successful"))
    case r => Future.successful(r.collect({ case Success(x) => x}))
}
```

Comment: Yes but i used future sequence to convert List[Future[Try[AbcDto]]] to Future[List[Try[AbcDto]]]

Comment: @Sidhant I have updated the answer. please take a look

Comment: case r: List[Try[AbcDto]]. At this point its giving error:
non-variable type argument scala.util.Try[AbcDto] in type pattern List[scala.util.Try[AbcDto]] (the underlying of List[scala.util.Try[AbcDto]])

Comment: And actually here in your code type of a is :List[Future[Any]]

Comment: `Future[Try[_]]` stacking rarely makes sense, would rather flatten using `Future.fromTry`

Answer (score 1):

`Future[A]` and `Try[A]` in the actor context are so similar that I see no point to return `Try[A]` from those actors. You just return `A` in case of success, which will be `Future[A]` on `ask`ing side, a `List` of which you can `sequence` and get `Future[List[A]]`, which, in case of a single failure, will contain the first encountered exception. It seems to be exactly what you're asking for.

To communicate failure from an actor to the `ask`er, you should send `akka.actor.Status.Failure` with the relevant instance of `Throwable`.

P.S. regarding comment that using `try-catch` is non-idiomatic Scala. It actually is. Here's how `Try` creation is implemented:

```
object Try {
  /** Constructs a `Try` using the by-name parameter.  This
   * method will ensure any non-fatal exception is caught and a
   * `Failure` object is returned.
   */
  def apply[T](r: => T): Try[T] =
    try Success(r) catch {
      case NonFatal(e) => Failure(e)
    }
}
```

As you can see, it uses `try-catch` inside. If Scala standard library authors are fine with that, so should be you. :)

Comment: So you are saying that i should put my actor code in try catch block. If no exception sender ! results. But if exception occurs i should use akka.actor.Status.Failure so that the ask receiver does not time out?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean.

Comment: But for that i need to put my code in a try catch block. Thats a little anti scala right?

Comment: Not at all. If you need to deal with exceptions, you use try-catch. Just have a look how `Try` itself is implemented. Or you can still catch exceptions via `Try`, but immediately convert it into `Future` via `Future.fromTry`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly (the types in your question are a bit confusing),

You start with a `val responseFutures: List[Future[Any]]` and after conversion you have a `val responsesFuture: Future[List[Any]]`. rogue-ones answer is correct, but it could use some clarification:

Your compiler error is caused by the fact that `Success` is not a class, but an extractor `object` with `unapply` for `Try`. Therefore you cannot use in in type extraction this way.

So something like `case r: List[Try[AbcDto]] if r.forall(_.isSuccess) => println("hello")` should compile. However, as `AbcDto` is erased, you will get a compiler warning about erasure. Thus the `@unchecked`.

**UPDATE**

Type erasure means, the compiler cannot check type argument type in pattern matches at compile time. In your case, all the compile knows of your input type is `Future[List[Try[Any]]]`.

So

```
future.map {
  case _: List[Try[AbcDto]] => ???
}
```

will cause a compiler warning because the compiler only sees.

```
future.map {
  case _: List[Try[_]] => ???
}
```

The `@unchecked` annotation just suppresses the corresponding compiler warning.

In the end with the pattern match above you just cast whatever is coming in to `Try[AbcDto]` without any compile time type safety.

Comment: What is meant by AbcDto is erased? and what is uncheked exactly?

Comment: @Sidhant Updated my answer with a brief explanation. Please refer to scala documetation for more information.